# swift how to update one to many relational data in coredata

Tags: ios, core-data, swift5

I created two table name A and B with core data like:

```
TABLE ZA 

Z_PK INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
Z_ENT INTEGER,
Z_OPT INTEGER, 
ZCREATEDATE VARCHAR, 
ZLASTUPDATETIME VARCHAR, 
ZTITLE VARCHAR

TABLE ZB 

Z_PK INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
Z_ENT INTEGER, 
Z_OPT INTEGER, 
ZORIGIN INTEGER, 
ZCREATEDATE VARCHAR, 
ZLASTUPDATETIME VARCHAR, 
ZSUBTITLE VARCHAR
```

the table's relationship is one to many, in table B, lastUpdateTime, createDate, subTitle is not unique, Z_PK is a primary key but created by core data automatically and i can't get it in the code.
if i want to update table B's item, how can i do that?

these code was not work for me:

```
let context = getContext()
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "B")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "Z_PK=\(item.value(forKey: "Z_PK"))", "")
```

UPDATE:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do not bother with the sqlite db file when using core data. Post the core data entity setup and let us know what exactly you want to fetch.

Comment: @shallowThought I have update the content, and i want to update entity B's lastUpdateTime  title attribute value.

Comment: Which "content" did you update? Do you have a reference to the updated object of type A? Post your update code.

Comment: You should not concern yourself with the underlying sqlite implementation at all. Not in the code or in any predicates or similar, never! You should think and code in terms of classes (entities) and properties (attributes). I can't help you with your predicate though since I don't understand what you want to do here. Maybe you could explain in words what object you want to fetch.

Comment: You seem to be trying to use Core Data like you would use SQLite, but that's not how Core Data works. It uses SQLite internally but it's not a SQLite wrapper and its public interface is very different. If you could describe what you're trying to accomplish a little more, it might be possible to help.